# How do if and else statements behave in a while loop (Python)?

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop

I'm watching [this](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-00-introduction-to-computer-science-and-programming-fall-2008/video-lectures/lecture-3/) course and at 28:25 it includes this code:

```
x = 4.5
ans = 0
if x>= 0:
    while ans*ans < x:
        ans = ans +1
    if ans*ans != x:
        print (x, 'is not a perfect square')
    else: print (ans)
else: print (x, ' is a negative number')
```

[Code Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Yn9R.jpg)

I don't get the while loop-- does it keep iterating that over and over and THEN checks the if statement? Or does it check the if statement each time it iterates? I feel rather stupid!

Would appreciate some help-- I imagine if I applied myself more I'd get it-- but this stuff is very different from music and philosophy.

(Ah-- got it now-- I didn't think through the indentation. The if and else under while will only take place after the while loop breaks because they're not "inside" the while loop. I swear I get dumber every day. Or maybe it's been a long time since I've done any truly out of domain thinking.)

Comment: while will keep iterate as long as ```ans*ans < x``` then executing ```ans = ans +1```, it will break if ```ans*ans >= x```, and continue to if statement below it, which is ```if ans*ans != x:```

Comment: ```if``` and ```else``` on line 6 and 8 has no relationship with ```while``` on line 4

Comment: does it keep iterating that over and over and THEN checks the if statement? yes, as long as ```ans*ans < x```

Comment: It helps to convert things like `else: print (ans)` into multiple lines with indentation. It makes the flow easier to spot and is better for stepping through with a debugger. And learn a python debugger! Then you can step through the program line by lline and see what it does.

Answer (score 1):

Since the `if ans*ans < x:` is not inside the while loop, the while loop keeps iterating until `ans*ans < 4.5`, and then it checks the if statement. It **doesn't** check the `if ans*ans != x:` each time the while loop iterates.

Comment: Got it-- thank you. If and else are only checked after the while loop breaks. And I guess the if and else do cover the only options for potential answers.

Answer (score 0):

`trace` can help visual program flow. Since there aren't too many step here, you can show each line executed then go back to the source to compare.

```
$ python3 -m trace --trace test.py
 --- modulename: test, funcname: <module>
test.py(1): x = 4.5
test.py(2): ans = 0
test.py(3): if x>= 0:
test.py(4):     while ans*ans < x:
test.py(5):         ans = ans +1
test.py(4):     while ans*ans < x:
test.py(5):         ans = ans +1
test.py(4):     while ans*ans < x:
test.py(5):         ans = ans +1
test.py(4):     while ans*ans < x:
test.py(6):     if ans*ans != x:
test.py(7):         print (x, 'is not a perfect square')
4.5 is not a perfect square
```